# Obtain only names after "#" from SPARQL query

Tags: java, sparql, jena, ontology, owl

I have this java code that, using apache jena api, queries the pizza ontology

```
    String queryStr =
"prefix pizza: <" + PIZZA_NS + "> "               +
"prefix rdfs: <" + RDFS.getURI() + "> "           +
"prefix owl: <" + OWL.getURI() + "> "             +
"select ?pizza where {?pizza a owl:Class ; "      +
"rdfs:subClassOf ?restriction. "                  +
"?restriction owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping ;"  +
"owl:someValuesFrom pizza:PeperoniSausageTopping" +
"}";


Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryStr);
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
ResultSet rs = qe.execSelect();


ArrayList rsList = (ArrayList)ResultSetFormatter.toList(rs);
for(int i=0;i<rsList.size();i++){
    out.println(rsList.get(i).toString());
}
```

It returns this:

```
( ?pizza = <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#AmericanHot> )
( ?pizza = <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#FourSeasons> )
( ?pizza = <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#American> )
```

but I need only

> AmericanHot
>
> FourSeasons
>
> American

How to obtain this result?

Comment: i think there should be one more link over to the text for each of those items

Comment: @Randy sorry I don't understand, I'm new with SPARQL, what does it mean?

Comment: I'm guessing that what he means is you shouldn't be trying to use the bit behind the # as the 'human readable name' of the resource. Instead, you should query for the `rdfs:label` property connected to each URI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SPARQL 1.1 function STRAFTER can help:

```
SELECT ?pizza (strafter(str(?pizza), "#") AS ?localName)
WHERE
```

but the client side solution is just as good and works with SPARQL 1.0.

Answer (score 7):

I solved it in this way.

```
for ( ; rs.hasNext() ; ){
  QuerySolution soln = rs.nextSolution() ;
  RDFNode x = soln.get("pizza") ;
  out.println(x.asNode().getLocalName());
}
```

For who will have my same question, other information can retrieve from [here](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/app_api.html)